# How to limit the stack depth

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Below is a simplified version of code that I've written. Basically there are objects that receive messages, do something with them and then pass them on (they implement `IState`) and objects which send the messages (which implement `ISend`). The problem is that I'm getting very deep stack traces which eventually result in a stack overflow. How can I get around this?

```
public class StackTraceMain {
    private IState origin;

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        StackTraceMain s = new StackTraceMain();
        s.prepare();
        s.go();
    }

    public void prepare(){
        Sender sendTo2 = new Sender();
        Sender sendTo1 = new Sender();
        origin = new State(sendTo2);
        IState state2 = new State(sendTo1);
        sendTo2.setTarget(state2);
        sendTo1.setTarget(origin);
    }

    public void go(){
        origin.update(new DataTuple(0));
    }

    private class State implements IState {
        private final ISend sender;

        public State(ISend sender) {
            this.sender = sender;
        }

        @Override
        public void update(DataTuple data) {
            int num = data.getInteger(0);
            num++;
            System.out.println("Sending " + num + ", depth: " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace().length);
            if (num < 1000)
                sender.signal(new DataTuple(num));
        }       
    }

    private class Sender implements ISend {
        private IState target;

        public void setTarget(IState target){
            this.target = target;
        }

        @Override
        public void signal(DataTuple data) {
            target.update(data);        
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: It takes a long time to get to the exception so it'll take me while to post it. Why would using a different event bus help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a infinity recursive function calls, use a [`SingleThreadedExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()), and use that to dispatch the update calls.

Because this executor is single threaded, you don't need to worry about concurrent actions making weird changes.

To make this change, we make a global thread pool at the start of the application:

```
public final static ExecutorService GLOBAL_APPLICATION_THREAD = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

And then we change the update method to:

```
@Override
public void update(DataTuple data) {
    GLOBAL_APPLICATION_THREAD.execute( () -> { // Create lamba function
        int num = data.getInteger(0);
        num++;
        System.out.println("Sending " + num + ", depth: " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace().length);
        if (num < 1000)
            sender.signal(new DataTuple(num));
        }    
    });
}
```

When you then run the newly created code, you see that the stack size stays constant, this is because the the addiction of the Executor unrolled the recursion to something that looks like a loop where you can add elements while looping.

The best way to see how this works is understanding that `execute` doesn't execute it directly, but it puts it in a waiting row of tasks to be executed, and only at the point the whole function stack ends, it will execute a new function. The loop in this `Executor` can be seen as the following:

```
// Demonstration code only, may not feature best practices
LinkedList<Runnable> q = new LinkedList<>();
while(true) {
    Runnable task = q.remove(); // removes the first element
    task.execute()
}
```

When you try to execute a new task it basicly does `q.add(...)`, and thus waits for the execution until the current running task is done.

Comment: @Johnny Edited the post, just see the `Executor` as a list where you can add Runnables to, in combination with a dedicated thread that reads all tasks from it,

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent a `StackOverflow` by changing the parameter `-Xss` of your java application (or your application server).

If instead you have **too many deep calls** and it is not possible to find a reasonable value for the stack dimension to prevent the stackOverflow **you need to reenginering your application to remove some call**. For example **you can convert a recursive function to a standard loop**.

Comment: I agree that some change needs to be implemented, but I'm not sure which. There are two `IState`  objects which must act on the same message over and over.